# Python Beautiful Soup Getting Child from parent

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know how to get the parent from a child but how would I get the child from a parent:

```
aaa = soup.findAll(string=re.compile('Last 30 days'))
Views = aaa[0].findParent().text
```

The above gets me the Parent. But if i do:

```
aaa = soup.findAll(string=re.compile('Last 30 days'))
Views = aaa[0].findChild().text
```

It does not work and comes out with the error 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'findChild. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Because you are searching for text, which returns set of `NavigableString` and so `aaa[0]` is a `NavigableString`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to python, what code should be done to get the child?

Comment: Get the tags containing those texts then navigate to children.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to get the tags, once I get the tags what do I code to get the children?

Comment: E.g My if tag is class and top and the text is last 30 days then a <br> 20, how do I get the 20?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you give the link of the webpage ?

Comment: http://m.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/44118383?search_identifier=47a3930658506a6c528d84b2daa2463d

Comment: I'm trying to get the first listed 11th June 2017 part

Comment: http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/44118383?search_identifier=e31406ce57c4397baa6701b11e7cdab1

Comment: correct link above

Comment: filter out the div by class="sidebar sbt" then get the text and process it.

Comment: filtering out by soup.findAll('div' :{'class', 'sidebar sbt'}) ...how do i get the text from that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the necessary `div` by `class = sidebar sbt`. Use `get_text()` to get the texts of each `div` and check if this `div` contains your necessary info. Then find `p` to exclude unnecessary `texts`, use `get_text()` and strip out excess spaces and new lines. Split the string by space and get the list 3 elements of the list. Join again to get your desired `string`.

N.B: There might be easier way to process the `string`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/44118383?search_identifier=e31406ce57c4397baa6701b11e7cdab1"

html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="sidebar sbt")

for div in divs:
    text = div.get_text().lower()
    if(text.find("first listed") > -1):
        text = div.find("p").get_text()
        text = text.replace("\n","",10)
        text = text.strip()
        text_list = text.split()[-3:]
        text = " ".join(text_list)
        print(text)
        break
```

If you need the whole `string` of First Listed part, avoid splitting and joining.